# Ubuntu on EC2 boot error after dist upgrade to 14.04: disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mount, boot, ubuntu-14.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 11.10 EC2 instance to 12.04, then to 12.10 and finally to 14.04 using the `do-release-upgrade` command each time. I arrived at 14.04 and the instance will not boot now, it hangs indefinitely at startup with the following in the log: `disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present`.

This is the root volume of the instance. I detached it from the instance, launched a brand new instance with an 8GB root volume containing a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, and attached the problem volume to the new instance at `/data` so I could poke around.

The release info tells me the distribution is 14.04. `/data/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# <file system>     <mount point>     <type>    <options>    <dump>    <pass>
proc    /proc     proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0      0
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs    ext4    defaults      0       0
/dev/xvdf1     /mnt/nightly-update-disk       ext4      defaults     0      0
```

There's nothing at all in `/data/dev`, it's empty. `ls /data` looks like:

```
bin   dev   home     initrd.img.old  libnss3.so  media       opt   root  sbin    
sys   usr   vmlinuz  boot            etc         initrd.img  lib   lost+found   
mnt   proc  run      srv             tmp         var         vmlinuz.old
```

I'm not a linux admin so I'm not that familiar with what I should be looking out for.
There are a good few questions around with the `disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present` error for Ubuntu, and the most common solution is to choose the manual recovery option at boot and run `mount -o remount, rw /`. But I don't have that kind of access during startup of an EC2 instance, I just see the startup log. Is there something I can do on the attached volume once I've gotten access to it using the cleanly installed volume?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/410560/308532) looks like a possible solution to your problem. That is, the label for your root partition has changed, so on boot, / isn't able to be mounted becasue cloudimg-rootfs doesn't exist.

If this is the case, you can change the label with e2label /dev/sdX <label>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I run `e2label /dev/xvdf` I get `cloudimg-rootfs` (xvdf is my problem volume, at least that's what sdf gets transformed into). In that case, what would I need to change the label to? I also tried replacing the `LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs` to `/dev/xvda1` in fstab and tried booting with the problem volume at sda1 (xvda/xvda1) but the startup still hangs.

Comment: Did you every get this work? We're considering a similar upgrade.

Comment: Unfortunately I never managed to fix this. It may not happen for you, but make sure you create snapshots of your volumes before upgrading if you do decide to.

Comment: Is it fair to assume this instance is gone at this point and the question is unanswerable?

Comment: It certainly is gone. That's not to say that someone couldn't provide further useful information about a possible fix, but I can't test it out. Should the q be closed?